# Maven deploy gives Failed to deploy artifacts: Broken Pipe

Tags: maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci, artifacts

I am using a self-managed instance of GitLab with shared runners and a dind model for building my packages.

When I do mvn deploy, I am getting a

`Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact....Broken pipe (Write failed) ->`

the full error can be seen [here](https://pastebin.com/0rErAzM9) (the error message was too big for the 30k restriction on SO)

I am not sure what is going wrong here as the screenshot below shows, the pom files for the same folder are getting uploaded fine. So it does not looks like an access/permission issue.

[image]

Comment: I tried using the gitlab api to transfer the jar from the docker container using the same token defined in settings.xml and it is going through and I am able to see the jars in the package registry